# Questions of Generating Simulated Data

Tags: quantitative-finance, dolphindb

I generated the simulated data, the scripts is shown as following:

```py
def writeData(mutable t , dbName, tableName, days){ 
    pt = loadTable(dbName,tableName); for(i in days){ 
        update t set date = i;
        pt.append!(t);
 } }
def main(dbName, tableName, days){ 
    pt = loadTable(dbName, tableName); 
    mr(pt,writeData(, dbName, tableName, days), parallel=true); 
}
dbName = "dfs://level2"; 
tableName = `quotes; 
days = (2020.06.01..2020.06.30)[weekday(2020.06.01..2020.06.30) between 1:5 ]; 
main(dbName, tableName, days);
```

The update reported by the error is not a table object, and then modify it with loadTableBySQL, and the error message is the same:

```py
t = loadTableBySQL(<select * from pt where date=2020.06.01>);
mr(t,writeData(, dbName, tableName, days), parallel=true);
```

Answer (score 0):

the parameters of mr function you passed in is wrong

```py
mr(pt,writeData(, dbName, tableName, days), parallel=true);
```

It should be modified as the following:

```py
mr(t,writeData{, dbName, tableName, days}, parallel=true);
```

The {} represents a partial application which can fix the first parameter. Please refer to [partialApplication](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/Functionalprogramming/PartialApplication.html) for more details.